# Get row id in tableview options

Tags: ios, swift

I am using swipe gesture for tableview cell options.

**This is my code:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Sil" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in


        let shareMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Emin misiniz ?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let twitterAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Sil", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: self.deleteConversation)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "İptal", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

        shareMenu.addAction(twitterAction)
        shareMenu.addAction(cancelAction)


        self.presentViewController(shareMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
    return [shareAction]

}
```

You can see in the code, i am using `deleteConversation` method for handler. But I don't know how to get row id in `deleteConversation` method.

This is my `deleteConversation` method:

```
func deleteConversation(alert: UIAlertAction!) {
    //I need the row id here
    println("sill")
}
```

How can I get the row id in handler method ?

Comment: Why don't you just have a variable declared for indexPath, and save it in function and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of choices. You can save the row/indexPath of the edit action to a new instance variable at the beginning of your editActionsForRowAtIndexPath, and then look at that instance variable in your deleteConversation function. (You would need to create a new class-wide instance variable in your view controller for this option to work.)

Second option: You can pass in an inline block in your call to create the twitter action:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
  editActionsForRowAtIndexPath   
  indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? 
{
  //skipped code here...
  let twitterAction = UIAlertAction(
    title: "Sil", 
    style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, 
    handler: 
    {
      (alert: UIAlertAction!)  in
      println("User asked to delete twitter feed at index \(indexPath.row)")
    })
  //skipped more code here...
}
```

With that syntax you are passing in a closure as the twitter action handler, and defining the closure in-line. When you do that the closure has access to the variables in it's enclosing scope. In this case it gives us access to the indexPath that's passed in.

Answer (score 1):

```
Class YourClassNameHere

var cellIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

// Other stuff here...

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath   indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

cellIndexPath = indexPath

var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Sil" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in


    let shareMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Emin misiniz ?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let twitterAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Sil", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: self.deleteConversation)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "İptal", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

    shareMenu.addAction(twitterAction)
    shareMenu.addAction(cancelAction)


    self.presentViewController(shareMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
return [shareAction]

}

func deleteConversation(alert: UIAlertAction!) {
  //Print row indexpath here
  println("sill \(cellIndexPath.row)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume by `ID` you mean `indexPath`?
In order to get it, have you tried using `indexPathForSelectedRow` on `self.tableView`?

Comment: Yes i mean indexPath. Could you give an example ?